# How can I append one single char at the end of a new filename?

Tags: c, pointers, char, append

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int fd_src = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);

    ssize_t size = lseek(fd_src, 0, SEEK_END);

    char *buf[size];

    char *prefix = strcat(argv[1], "_");

    for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {

        lseek(fd_src, i, SEEK_SET);

        read(fd_src, buf, 1);

        char *postfix = &buf[0];

        char *filename = strcat(prefix, postfix);

        int fd_dest = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644);

        write(fd_dest, buf, 1);

        close(fd_dest);

    }

    close(fd_src);

    return 0;

}
```

The input-file "filename" only contains the string "abc"

After I run the program, the output looks like that:

filename_a   // file contains a
filename_ab  // file contains b
filename_abc // file contains c

But I would like it to look like that:

filename_a   // file contains a
filename_b   // file contains b
filename_c   // file contains c

I have already tried to declare the postfix like that:

char *postfix = &buf[i]

But that didn't work either. Any suggestions? :)

Comment: Making `buf` an array of pointers makes no sense, especially since that's not how you use it (and you misuse it badly anyway).

Comment: As for your problem, you need to copy all the arguments into an array, large enough to hold the full string including null-terminator. You're not allowed to modify command-line arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *prefix = strcat(argv[1], "_");
```

it is wrong as you attach one character to the string kept in the argv[1] and argv[1] is very unlikely to be big enough to accommodate it. It is very likely undefined behaviour.

From your code, I understand that you want to append the file name the first character of the file content.

```
char filename[strlen(argv[1] + 3];
/* ... */
sprintf(filename, "%s_%c", argv[1], buf[0]);  // you need to change the type of buf
```

```
char *buf[size];
```

it is an array of pointers not characters. It will work as `sizeof(char *) is always > sizeof(char)`, but you need an array of characters.

```
char buf[size];
```

Comment: It works perfectly now. Another question regarding the content of the files. I would like to append every character for which a new file has been created. So, if a letter appears more than one time in a string, I would like to append it to that specific file. if the new fileis named "filename_a" and the string in the original input file contains more than one 'a', I would like to output it in the file "filename_a" as "aa". Any ideas? :-)

Comment: `sprintf(filename, "%s_%c%c", argv[1], buf[0], buf[0]);` and you need longer array

Comment: I would like to append the character to the end of the file content. So, if I open the file, I would like to read "aa" instead of "a" (if 'a' appears two times in the input file).

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it... I recognized that I had set the flag "O_EXCL". It works now as it should. :-)